# Linq to Sql including 2 children sets

Tags: c#, linq

Using Entity Framework 6.

I have a City class which has a collection of CoreClass. Each CoreClass has a collection of CorePersons and CoreBooks. Think of a 'school' model.

To include the CoreBooks in the query I use:

```
.Include(e=>e.CoreClass.Select(i=>i.CoreBooks))
```

But how do I get the person records of the CorePersons:

```
 .Include(e=>e.CoreClass.Select(i=>i.CorePersons.Person?????))
```

Comment: LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Include(e=>e.CoreClass.Select(i=>i.CoreBooks))
.Include(e=>e.CoreClass.Select(i=>i.CorePersons.Select(o => o.Person)))
```